# How to authenticate a call to a private google cloud function from a container on a VM on the vpc?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, bearer-token

In GCP, I have a Compute Engine VM on the default VPC running docker.  I have a container app (python fastAPI web app) that needs to call a private cloud function to post some data using requests.

```
head = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    resp = requests.post(url, 
                        data = msgObj,
                        headers = head,
                        timeout=1.50
                        )
```

This is all working fine, but the call to the private cloud function needs Bearer Authorization.  I can't seem to find a way to programmatically get this token.  I can get a token for testing by using
`gcloud auth print-identity-token > token.txt` on the host VM.  This works, but is not acceptable for production use.
Any thoughts?

I have tried to use a token generated by another private cloud function that posts data to the container app.

```
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const token = await auth.getAccessToken();
```

But this token didn't work. (401 Unauthorized)
Getting the token via gcloud (see above) from the VM host works, but is obviously hardcoded and will not work for long - only testing.
This use case (calling a private cloud function from a container) doesn't seem to be covered by anything I can find.  There is a video on how to do this from google but was useless - basically saying to use the gcloud approach above.

Comment: Are you sure that the service account of your Compute Engine VM has the permission to invoke the Cloud Function?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for commenting!   Yes, the error I was getting was  "Unauthorized", not "Forbidden" which was the case before I updated the permissions.

Comment: What are the authorized scopes of your Compute Engine service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually straightforward once I found it from several clues.

1. `add google-auth=2.6.2`  to the requirements doc for the container
2. add the following to your container code

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token


    audience = function_url
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)
```

Then use the id_token in the header for the function call

```
    head = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + id_token
        }
    resp = requests.post(audience, 
                        data = msgObj,
                        headers = head
                        )
```